# validation for email oracle apex to accept "-"

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

In Apex, my validation for email text fields is rejecting `jean-pierre.daltin@oracle.com` because of the `"-"` (hyphen).

Please help me modify the below regular expression to allow this email address.

I'm using this regex for validating email:

```
^(([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)(\s*,\s*|\s*$))*$
```

Comment: The RFC covering email addresses does not restrict the part before the @ to such a narrow range.

Comment: http://emailregex.com/

Comment: Try this : /^(\".\"|[-A-Za-z]\w)@([\d{1,3}(.\d{1,3}){3}]|[A-Za-z]\w*(.[A-Za-z]\w*)+)$/ . It will allow '-' before the '@'

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+$
```